# How to connect Java SocketIO to Javascript Server

Tags: javascript, java, socket.io

I have a javascript server `server.js`

```js
const http = require("http").createServer()
const io = require("socket.io")(http)   

io.on("connection", socket => {
    console.log("a user connected")
})

http.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log("listening on *:3000")
})
```

and a java client `SocketIO.java`

```java
package chess_client;

import java.net.URISyntaxException;

import io.socket.client.IO;
import io.socket.client.Socket;
import io.socket.emitter.Emitter;

public class SocketIO {
    private static Socket socket;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws URISyntaxException {
        socket = IO.socket("http://localhost:3000");

        socket.on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT, new Emitter.Listener() {

            @Override
            public void call(Object... args) {
                System.out.println("Connected!");
            }

        });

        socket.connect();
    }
}
```

I've been searching for Javascript Server & Java Client examples but the example on https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-java only shows the Java Client example without the Javascript Server code. When combining both, nothing works. I don't see anything in either of the terminals when I run both codes!!! What's wrong???
For any answers given, do note that I would prefer using Typescript than Javascript but both are acceptable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found my answer after the Java SocketIO client was updated. I made some mistakes.

1. I need the npm package for `socket.io` to be version 2.*
   The documentation stated that for a version of `1.*` for the Java Client, the SocketIO server must be of version `2.*`. At this time, `2.3.0` is the latest npm package for `socket.io` so install that instead of version `3.*`.
2. I'm assuming the Java Client is of a different host because it's not rendered by the server itself. For example, this is the code on the official SocketIO documentation:

```js
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});
```

In this example, the Javascript server is directly rendering the HTML file so
However, the Java code can't be run by a Javascript server. This is why when creating the `const io`, we should change it to:

```js
const io =  require('socket.io')(http, {
    cors: { origin: '*' }
})
```

This allows code of any host - or origin - to access the SocketIO server.

Here's an example of my working Java Client and Javascript Server if anyone needs the reference
`app.js`:

```js
const http = require('http').createServer()

const io =  require('socket.io')(http, {
    cors: { origin: '*' }
})

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log('Connected to client!')

    io.emit('time', Date.now())
})

http.listen(8080, () => console.log('Server running on port 8080'))
```

`App.java`:

```java
package socket_test;

import java.net.URISyntaxException;

import io.socket.client.IO;
import io.socket.client.Socket;
import io.socket.emitter.Emitter;

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws URISyntaxException {
        Socket socket = IO.socket("http://localhost:8080");
        socket.on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT, new Emitter.Listener() {

            @Override
            public void call(Object... args) {
                System.out.println("Connected to server!");
            }

        });
        socket.on("time", new Emitter.Listener() {
            
            @Override
            public void call(Object... args) {
                System.out.println("Time: " + args[0]);
            }
            
        });
        socket.connect();
    }
}
```